# Is it possible to change the size of the 'icon' property when selecting a Marker widget in google_maps_flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm using the google_maps_flutter package to display a map, and I want to change the size of the icon of the tapped Marker widget when it's tapped (onTap). However, I haven't been able to come up with a method to achieve this.
The only method I could think of is to generate a different 'icon' of a different size for another Marker widget when the original Marker widget is tapped, and then overlay it at the same Position. However, this approach has some issues.

So, apart from the method of creating a different Marker and overlaying it on top of the tapped Marker, is there any other way to change the size of the icon specified in the 'icon' property of the tapped Marker without generating separate Markers?

postscript:
There are multiple Markers, and I want to change the `icon` size of the tapped (OnTap) Marker.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation you can change the icon of the marker by re-rendering the bitmap, check this example code from official library:

[marker_icons.dart](https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/main/packages/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter/example/lib/marker_icons.dart)

```
      final ImageConfiguration imageConfiguration =
          createLocalImageConfiguration(context, size: const Size.square(48));
      _markerIcon = await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
              imageConfiguration, 'assets/red_square.png');        
      Marker(
        markerId: const MarkerId('marker_1'),
        position: _kMapCenter,
        icon: _markerIcon!,
      )
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I forgot to mention in my initial question, but I assumed that there are multiple Markers placed on the map. Also, the source you provided seems to not have changed the size of the icon.

Comment: Not quite in the source, but when rendering de Bitmap you can asign a Size to it.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.
As for the question itself, I would like to change the size of the icon when the Marker is tapped.